# How to pass a props to event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

- I would like to pass a custom props to the `onClick` handler.
- I cannot return an inline function as below, because I will have to later fire redux action creator as part of the handler (async action is not allowed)

```
onClick={()=>this.handleClick("v")}
```

- Using middleware seems an overkill to me..
- For simplicity purpose, please just ignore the redux part. Just say we can't use inline arrow function like this.

The example code below is just a POC approach that I borrow from `input` component, where `value` is an inherited props.
I am OK with any props("custom" as I said)

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    handleClick = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.value);

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <label
                    value="v" 
                    onClick={this.handleClick}
                >
                    TEST Label
                </label>
            </div>
        )

}
```

I expect console log to output a custom value -- "v"

Comment: use mapDispatchToProps to pass action to the components and call it similar to above.

Comment: connect(mapStateToProps,{actions1, action2})(Component) not action1 and action2 should be available in props. call them directly like ordinary function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your options are really limited. You should either use the inline arrow function and handle you async whatever problem in some other way or you should find a way to keep your state updated with current value of your label value. If it was an input `onChange = {this.handleChange}` would do it. this way your code will look like this:

```js
handleClick(){
    const {value} = this.state;
    doSomething(value)
}
updateValue(input){
/*    this.setState({
        value : input
    })*/
    //in your case :
    this.setState({
        value : 'v'
    })
}
render(){
    return(
        <label 
            value= {this.state.value}
            onClick={this.handleClick}
        >Text</label>
    )
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Yeah. I recon this is a valid answer after researching. A bit disappointed that the event object itself doesn't contain the props of the component though.

Answer (score 0):

use **mapDispatchToProps** to pass action to the components and call it similar to above.

```
import React from "react";

import { action1 } from "./actions";

const App = ({action1})=> (
  <button onClick={()=>action1("one")}>Click Me</button>
  );

export default connect(null, {action1})(App);
```

Comment: This won't work. As I said, async action is not allowed. Let's take redux out of the picture for simpler discussion.

Comment: It will do look into mapDispatchtoProps docs https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch

Comment: This is exactly my original approach and hit async problem. Maybe I did something wrong in the redux side... But let's say, as the title, I really want to pass a custom props to event handler. Forget about redux.

Comment: Sorry for being picky. I just want to minimize the discussion without involving another big chunk of redux code...